# Not able to access Remote Elasticsearch Instance from NodeJs Application

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch 6.5 instance installed on Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS. I also have a NodeJS application, which needs to communicate with it remotely. 
My NodeJS application is working perfectly fine if ElasticSearch is locally installed, but not able to get response from the remote instance. I have modified the elasticsearch.yml file and changed the `network.host` setting to `network.host: 0.0.0.0`. 
I am able to query remote elasticsearch instance  using Postman, but my NodeJS application fails to connect. 
In my NodeJS application logs I can see, it's trying to connect to ElasticSearch via Elasticsearch host machine's internal IP, whereas in NodeJS configuration I have specified the public IP. 
Any leads on where I am making the configuration errors would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your NodeJS application is most likely trying to query elasticsearch using the address that elasticsearch publishes. When setting network.host, elasticsearch automatically sets publish.host to the same value. I'm not sure what elasticsearch does when you ask it to publish 0.0.0.0, because elasticsearch can only publish one address (As opposed to listening, which it can do on several addresses).

Try setting `publish.host` to the address on which your NodeJS application can reach it. Keep in mind that the other elasticsearch nodes needs to be able to connect to this address aswell.

The relevant documentation is here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html